# How to fix display images and flashing text in wordpress (cache)

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

Ive installed plugins like w3 total cache and autoptimize for optimizing my website. However my images and certain flashing text are gone? Ive deleted the plugins , yet my site is still isn't fix. https://benmicofficialph.com

Answer (score 0):

There are problem in your site for using **lazy load**.

So try to deactivate this plugin and try to clear cache and tel me what happen

Comment: hey man, it did  work for some!..  but my flash txt at my home page is not there , also some images are still not showing.any more suggestions bro ? :D also I don't exactly know how to clear my cache.

Comment: now I did use plugin WP Super Cache to clear my cache , still the same bro.

Comment: Hey man. I did the diggin' Turns out I was disabling a lot of features with plugin Speed Booster. Thank you man. But would you still consider me using Lazy Load?

Comment: You are still using Lazy Load, See this images from your site http://prntscr.com/n9grjf

Comment: lazy load does not crash my css when I view my site, but speed booster pack does, I would like to know how to lower my TTFB without jeopardizing the design in this site.

Comment: You have 2 error : 1- Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '_typeof' has already been declared ... 2- is from lazy see this ( http://prntscr.com/nb4387 )